# ffmpeg how to start encoding at live point (not from beginning)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, live

Is there a way with ffmpeg to start encoding at "live point" (in other words at last encoded frame...)

let met explain : 2 ffmpeg process

[1] x11grab that is being generated that started a 2:00 pm.... and still continue live (I don't want to stop and continue encoding live)

[2] restream the [1] but at live point (at where it is encoding now) not from start...

If [2] is being triggered at 2:15 pm, it will load the first frame of [1] (start to encode from 2pm)

but I want that it load the last few frames of [1] as a starting point (2:15pm)...

I know that I could `ffmpeg -i -ss` but I have to specify a x number of seconds after `-ss`...

is there a better way?

Comment: Where's the output of [1] going?

Comment: @Gyan [1] output is .mp4 or m3u8 with segments and [2]streaming to youtube, facebook, etc with `-f flv rtmp://....../key/.....`